# How to embed $foo->bar into string in Php

Tags: php

I'm new to Php,

`echo "$foo->bar"` seem to work as expected

`echo "this is {$foo->bar}"` works as well

what's the best way to do this?

Comment: If both examples you gave work as expected, what is the problem?

Comment: Any way that works for you is good.

Comment: I'd say you can use the first one in cases like this, for being slightly shorter.

Comment: @Dai I'm asking that, because in Vim the syntax highlighting doesn't work in either way. So I think there is a authentic way to do this

Comment: If it is a long string, the second way makes the variable inside the double quotes more noticeable.

Comment: please refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php to learn about string interpolation. There is no better or worse in this case.

Comment: That's a limitation of Vim and has nothing to do with the "preferred" way of doing something in PHP. PHP itself has many ways of doing the same thing (owing to its kitchen-sink approach). Other PHP IDEs (I use `VS.php` myself) provide syntax highlighting for embedded variables in strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to encode the text `$foo->bar` into a PHP string literally, then you need to escape it like so:

```
"\$foo->bar"
```

Or use single-quotes:

```
`$foo->bar`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
echo $foo->bar;
```

Because you're echoing a variable, you don't need quotes. So you could either concatenate or use double quotes (like you have):

```
echo 'text ' . $foo->bar . ' text';

echo "text $foo->bar text";
```

Comment: And if you want to show "$foo->bar" as is (without converting to the actual variable" , echo 'this is $foo->bar'; or echo "this is \$foo->bar" but I recommend the first one.